# Why is hex -> base64 so different from base64 -> hex using pack and unpack?

Tags: ruby, arrays, pack, unpack

I got this code working, which converts from hex to base64, and vice versa.  I got `to_base64` from another SO question, and I wrote `to_hex` with some guesswork and trial and error.

```
class String

  def to_base64
    [[self].pack("H*")].pack("m0")
  end

  def to_hex
    self.unpack("m0").first.unpack("H*").first
  end
end
```

But I don't really grok the `pack` and `unpack` methods, even after reading the docs.  Specifically, I'm confused by the asymmetry between the two implementations.  Conceptually, in both cases, we take a string encoded in some base (16 or 64), and we wish to convert it to another base.  So why can't we implement `to_hex` like this:

```
def to_hex
  [[self].pack("m0")].pack("H*")
end
```

or `to_base64` using `unpack`?  Why does the base we chose completely change the method we need to use to accomplish conversions?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`to_hex` is the exact inverse of `to_base64`:

#### `to_base64`

1. put string in an array: `[self]`
2. call pack with `H*`: `[self].pack("H*")`
3. put string in an array: `[[self].pack("H*")]`
4. call pack with `m0`: `[[self].pack("H*")].pack("m0")`

#### `to_hex`

1. call unpack with `m0`: `self.unpack("m0")`
2. extract string from array: `self.unpack("m0").first`
3. call unpack with `H*`: `self.unpack("m0").first.unpack("H*")`
4. extract string from array: `self.unpack("m0").first.unpack("H*").first`

That's how you undo operations, by applying the *inverse* operations:

```
a = 5
(a + 4) * 3
#=> 27
```

And the other way around:

```
a = 27
(a / 3) - 4
#=> 5
```

`a.pack` is the inverse of `a.unpack` and `a.first` is the inverse of `[a]`