# How do I get Rust's openssl crate to decrypt data from the symmetric-encryption gem without the gibberish that Node Crypto automatically removes?

Tags: rust, aes

I'm decrypting legacy data created by a Ruby on Rails application using the symmetric-encryption gem in Rust. See my earlier question [How do I decrypt data encrypted by Ruby's `symmetric-encryption` gem in another language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47661306/).

I've already implemented this in Node where the crypto library seems to know how to strip out gibberish in an encrypted string that Rust's [`openssl` crate](https://crates.io/crates/openssl) isn't stripping out (at least, the way I'm using it). I have already stripped out the PKCS7 padding and a header, yet it's still there. What is that gobbledygook, and how do I get Rust to remove it?

The encrypted data began as plaintext with a fixed-size header, was encrypted using AES-128-CBC with PKCS7 padding, and was then Base64 encoded. Using Node, I can decrypt it correctly using the following code:

```
const crypto = require("crypto");

const KEY = Buffer.from("1234567890ABCDEF");
const IV = Buffer.from("1234567890ABCDEF");
const CIPHERTEXT = Buffer.from("QEVuQwBAEACuPUPByDkk5jyNzQ3Wd3xTy2Isihz62XTLe1M5qKQrvw==", "base64");
const HEADER_SIZE = 8;
const ALGO = "aes-128-cbc";

const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv(ALGO, KEY, IV);

decipher.update(CIPHERTEXT.slice(HEADER_SIZE));
const result = decipher.final();

console.log([...result]);
console.log(result.toString());
```

The result is

```
[ 72, 97, 108, 102 ]
Half
```

I'd prefer to use Rust for the application I'm writing. Using the `openssl` crate, I can decode the encrypted data, but there's a bunch of junk that Node's library knows how to strip but Rust isn't stripping automatically the way I'm using it:

```
extern crate base64;
extern crate openssl;

use openssl::symm::*;

const KEY: &'static [u8] = b"1234567890ABCDEF";
const IV: &'static [u8] = b"1234567890ABCDEF";
const CIPHERTEXT: &'static str = "QEVuQwBAEACuPUPByDkk5jyNzQ3Wd3xTy2Isihz62XTLe1M5qKQrvw==";
const HEADER_SIZE: usize = 8;

fn main() {
    let decoded = base64::decode(&CIPHERTEXT).unwrap();
    let ciphertext = &decoded[HEADER_SIZE..];

    let result = decrypt(Cipher::aes_128_cbc(), KEY, Some(IV), ciphertext).unwrap();
    println!("{:?}", result);
    println!("{:?}", String::from_utf8_lossy(&result));
}
```

Here the result is

```
[221, 75, 14, 215, 54, 120, 246, 222, 194, 208, 53, 68, 127, 190, 124, 8, 72, 97, 108, 102]
"�K\u{e}�6x����5D\u{7f}�|\u{8}Half"
```

You can see that the last four bytes are correct, but that Node stripped out the preceding 16 bytes, as it appears it should have. I don't know what those bytes are.

At first I thought the 16 bytes of gibberish were from attempting to decrypt the PKCS7 padding. But I can verify that the padding was already stripped out: if I create a `Crypter` following the example in the `openssl` crate's [documentation](https://docs.rs/openssl/0.10.4/openssl/symm/struct.Crypter.html), but don't include the `truncate()` step, the resulting `Vec` has 12 consecutive `12`s—the PKCS7 padding—that were automatically removed.

So the gibberish is not PKCS7 padding, but I don't know what it is or how to get rid of it using Rust.

And to anticipate the Miranda warning about not futzing with crypto if I'm not an expert: this is not going to be used in production or to create data to put into production.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`decipher.update` [returns a `Buffer`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_decipher_update_data_inputencoding_outputencoding) which is ignored in the Node implementation. If you change the Node implementation to print the buffer returned from the update call, you can see that it's the same garbage data:

```
const buffer = decipher.update(CIPHERTEXT.slice(HEADER_SIZE));
console.log(buffer.toString());
```

Outputs:

```
�K�6x����5D�|
```

If you change the Rust version to ignore that portion of the output as well, you see the expected output:

```
extern crate base64;
extern crate openssl;

use openssl::symm::*;

const KEY: &'static [u8] = b"1234567890ABCDEF";
const IV: &'static [u8] = b"1234567890ABCDEF";
const CIPHERTEXT: &'static str = "QEVuQwBAEACuPUPByDkk5jyNzQ3Wd3xTy2Isihz62XTLe1M5qKQrvw==";
const HEADER_SIZE: usize = 8;

fn main() {
    let decoded = base64::decode(&CIPHERTEXT).unwrap();
    let ciphertext = &decoded[HEADER_SIZE..];

    let t = Cipher::aes_128_cbc();
    let mut d = Crypter::new(t, Mode::Decrypt, KEY, Some(IV)).unwrap();
    let mut result = vec![0; CIPHERTEXT.len() + t.block_size()];
    d.update(&ciphertext, &mut result).unwrap();
    let len = d.finalize(&mut result).unwrap();
    result.truncate(len);
    println!("{:?}", result);
    println!("{:?}", String::from_utf8_lossy(&result));
}
```

Outputs:

```
[72, 97, 108, 102]
"Half"
```

Comment: Great, I appreciate it. Out of curiosity, any idea what that garbage data is or where it would have come from?

Comment: No idea - I'd need to see at the code that did the encryption. Encrypting `Half` with that key and IV gives me `ZfIfn7CkScGMNiQHW9//vg==`, so it seems like there's something else happening on the encryption side.

Comment: Very good. I'll chalk it up to yet more idiosyncrasies with the `symmetric_encryption` gem, about which I asked a different [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47661306/how-do-i-decrypt-data-encrypted-by-rubys-symmetric-encryption-gem-in-another).

Comment: @EthanKent your existing question already contains the answer: *by default it adds a header to the output, and then base64 encodes it*

Comment: Okay, got it. I thought I was stripping the `symmetric_encryption` header with the line `let ciphertext = &decoded[HEADER_SIZE..];` line.

Comment: @EthanKent have you seen [the documentation in the code](https://github.com/rocketjob/symmetric-encryption/blob/v4.0.0/lib/symmetric_encryption/header.rb#L125-L144)? It seems to be much more than 8 bytes that you use here or the 6 bytes the other answer states...

Comment: Oh yeah, you're right. 

I wonder if it's a coincidence, then, that the combination of stripping 8 bytes plus the way the node `update()` method works just happened to swallow the 12(?) bytes of the header. Another person on the team finished implementing the Node code using the other answer, and I was trying to port their code to Rust—maybe they just tried different header values until it worked. Peculiar.

Answer (score 1):

Your Node decryption is **incorrect** and it only works because you are ignoring exactly the correct number of bytes before the data begins, as [sfackler explains](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49057357/155423).

[symmetric-encryption](https://github.com/rocketjob/symmetric-encryption/blob/v4.0.0/lib/symmetric_encryption/header.rb#L146-L187) pads the data with a header. The header has flexible length based on the options you are using. This code properly parses the entire header and then *uses the IV embedded in the header*:

```
extern crate base64;
extern crate openssl;
extern crate byteorder;

use openssl::symm::*;
use byteorder::{LittleEndian, ReadBytesExt};

use std::io::{self, Cursor, BufRead};

const KEY: &'static [u8] = b"1234567890ABCDEF";
//const IV: &'static [u8] = b"1234567890ABCDEF";
const CIPHERTEXT: &'static str = "QEVuQwBAEACuPUPByDkk5jyNzQ3Wd3xTy2Isihz62XTLe1M5qKQrvw==";

const FLAG_COMPRESSED: u8  = 0b1000_0000;
const FLAG_IV: u8          = 0b0100_0000;
const FLAG_KEY: u8         = 0b0010_0000;
const FLAG_CIPHER_NAME: u8 = 0b0001_0000;
const FLAG_AUTH_TAG: u8    = 0b0000_1000;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct EncryptedData<'a> {
    version: u8,
    compressed: bool,
    iv: Option<&'a [u8]>,
    key: Option<&'a [u8]>,
    cipher_name: Option<&'a [u8]>,
    auth_tag: Option<&'a [u8]>,
    data: &'a [u8],
}

impl<'a> EncryptedData<'a> {
    fn decode(decoded: &'a [u8]) -> Result<Self, io::Error> {
        let mut cursor = Cursor::new(decoded);

        let magic = {
            let raw = cursor.get_ref();
            let current = cursor.position() as usize;
            &raw[current..][..4]
        };
        cursor.consume(4);
        assert_eq!(b"@EnC", magic);

        let version = cursor.read_u8()?;
        let flags = cursor.read_u8()?;
        let compressed = flags & FLAG_COMPRESSED != 0;

        fn maybe_read_string<'b>(cursor: &mut Cursor<&'b [u8]>, flag: bool) -> Result<Option<&'b [u8]>, io::Error> {
            if flag {
                let len = cursor.read_u16::<LittleEndian>()? as usize;
                let data = {
                    let raw = cursor.get_ref();
                    let current = cursor.position() as usize;
                    Some(&raw[current..][..len])
                };
                cursor.consume(len);
                Ok(data)
            } else {
                Ok(None)
            }
        }

        let iv = maybe_read_string(&mut cursor, flags & FLAG_IV != 0)?;
        let key = maybe_read_string(&mut cursor, flags & FLAG_KEY != 0)?;
        let cipher_name = maybe_read_string(&mut cursor, flags & FLAG_CIPHER_NAME != 0)?;
        let auth_tag = maybe_read_string(&mut cursor, flags & FLAG_AUTH_TAG != 0)?;
        let data = {
            let raw = cursor.get_ref();
            let current = cursor.position() as usize;
            &raw[current..]
        };

        Ok(EncryptedData {
            version, compressed, iv, key, cipher_name, auth_tag, data,
        })
    }
}

fn main() {
    let decoded = base64::decode(&CIPHERTEXT).unwrap();
    let data = EncryptedData::decode(&decoded).unwrap();

    match decrypt(Cipher::aes_128_cbc(), KEY, data.iv, &data.data) {
        Ok(result) => {
            println!("{:?}", result);
            println!("{:?}", String::from_utf8_lossy(&result));
        }
        Err(e) => {
            println!("{}", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for that, it's very generous of you! I was going to start working with the `symmetric_encryption` source tomorrow, as I was still getting screwy results with some data. I also have a lot to learn about working with bytes, so I'm looking forward to working through this.

Comment: @EthanKent no problem; the fact that there were "magic" ignored bytes just really bothered me. You could certainly improve the `decode` function by making a new structure.

Comment: Yeah, I had the same sense that since I couldn't explain why the code worked, I wasn't super confident in it. We checked with some additional examples and found ones where the padding wasn't getting stripped out fully. I guess "it works but I don't know why" is a pretty strong signal that you're not done yet.

Comment: For anyone else who happens across this and is interested in the Node side of things, the exact way the Node implementation is wrong is that the results of the `update()` function and the `final()` function are supposed to be concatenated. See the [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_class_decipher). The author of the Node code ignored the output of `update()` as a hack (because it exactly swallowed up the header in the test cases we tried).